# Errors in my terminal when I use docker to start up a dockerised Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have an issue, Usually this works but today I had an error. I ran docker-compose up in my github codespaces terminal on VSCode to start up my postgres db, but when I typed in Localhost:8080 into my web browser I got the following error:

```
@JoshuaSmart-Olufemi ➜ /workspaces/DA_githubcodespace (main) $ docker-compose up
Starting da_githubcodespace_pgdatabase_1 ... done
Starting da_githubcodespace_pgadmin_1    ... done
Attaching to da_githubcodespace_pgadmin_1, da_githubcodespace_pgdatabase_1
pgdatabase_1  | 
pgdatabase_1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping 
initialization
pgdatabase_1  | 
pgdatabase_1  | 2024-01-25 15:17:51.117 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.13 (Debian 
13.13-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 
64-bit
pgdatabase_1  | 2024-01-25 15:17:51.121 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address 
"0.0.0.0", port 5432
pgdatabase_1  | 2024-01-25 15:17:51.121 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", 
port 5432
pgdatabase_1  | 2024-01-25 15:17:51.145 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket 
"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
pgdatabase_1  | 2024-01-25 15:17:51.176 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was interrupted; 
last known up at 2024-01-25 14:37:37 UTC
pgdatabase_1  | 2024-01-25 15:17:55.434 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was not properly 
shut down; automatic recovery in progress
pgdatabase_1  | 2024-01-25 15:17:55.446 UTC [26] LOG:  redo starts at 0/6B686570
pgdatabase_1  | 2024-01-25 15:17:55.446 UTC [26] LOG:  invalid record length at 
0/6B686658: wanted 24, got 0
pgdatabase_1  | 2024-01-25 15:17:55.446 UTC [26] LOG:  redo done at 0/6B686620
pgdatabase_1  | 2024-01-25 15:17:55.567 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
pgadmin_1     | [2024-01-25 15:17:59 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
pgadmin_1     | [2024-01-25 15:17:59 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
pgadmin_1     | [2024-01-25 15:17:59 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
pgadmin_1     | [2024-01-25 15:17:59 +0000] [82] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 82
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:22:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:22:20 +0000] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 2251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:22:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:22:22 +0000] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 2250 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:22:23 +0000] "GET /browser/js/endpoints.js?ver=80100 HTTP/1.1" 200 3118 "http://localhost:8080/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:22:23 +0000] "GET /tools/translations.js?ver=80100 HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "http://localhost:8080/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:52 +0000] "POST /authenticate/login HTTP/1.1" 302 205 "http://localhost:8080/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:52 +0000] "GET /browser/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2387 "http://localhost:8080/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:52 +0000] "GET /browser/browser.css?ver=80100 HTTP/1.1" 200 2862 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:53 +0000] "GET /browser/js/endpoints.js?ver=80100 HTTP/1.1" 200 3118 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:53 +0000] "GET /browser/js/messages.js?ver=80100 HTTP/1.1" 200 757 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:53 +0000] "GET /browser/js/utils.js?ver=80100 HTTP/1.1" 200 1895 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:53 +0000] "GET /browser/server/supported_servers.js?ver=80100 HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:53 +0000] "GET /tools/translations.js?ver=80100 HTTP/1.1" 200 321 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:53 +0000] "GET /user_management/current_user.js?ver=80100 HTTP/1.1" 200 274 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:53 +0000] "GET /browser/check_corrupted_db_file HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:53 +0000] "GET /misc/bgprocess/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:54 +0000] "GET /preferences/get_all HTTP/1.1" 200 9108 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:54 +0000] "GET /browser/nodes/ HTTP/1.1" 200 255 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:54 +0000] "POST /browser/master_password HTTP/1.1" 200 174 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:54 +0000] "GET /misc/upgrade_check HTTP/1.1" 200 77 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:23:56 +0000] "GET /browser/server_group/children/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin_1     | ::ffff:172.20.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:15:28:54 +0000] "POST /misc/cleanup HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://localhost:8080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

I also went on chatgpt and carried out the following commands:

```
docker-compose down -v

docker-compose up --build
```

But I got the same errors still.

this are the contents of my docker compose file:

```
services: pgdatabase: 
image: postgres:13 
environment: - POSTGRES_USER=root - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root - POSTGRES_DB=ny_taxi 
volumes: - "./ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw" 
ports: - "5432:5432" 
pgadmin: image: dpage/pgadmin4 
environment: - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=root 
#volumes: #- ./data_pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin 
ports: - "8080:80"
```

Comment: It is not clear which error you are getting. It looks that you re using pgAdmin, a Postgres web GUI used to interact with database sessions.You may be required to check how you are working with pgAdmin.

Comment: Please provide the contents of your `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: services:
  pgdatabase:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=ny_taxi
    volumes:
      - "./ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"  
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=root
    #volumes: 
      #- ./data_pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Your "error message" are just log outputs from Postgres/pgAdmin.